# Calling a class from another class with main method

Tags: java

In Java, can we call a main() method from another class? For example, ClassA is meant to be run on the command line as it has a main(String[] args) method defined.

I want to call this ClassA inside ClassB. Do I initialize a new object of the class, like

```
ClassA newobject = new ClassA()
```

or is there a way to pass the command line options of ClassA inside ClassB.

thanks

Comment: I think you can call it just like any other method.

Comment: You don't need to create an object of `ClassA` to call a `static` method like `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A.main(...string args here);
```

That's all there is to it because it's just a simple static void method. Fair bit of warning, it will be run in the same process and probably thread too as the caller. If what you are looking for is to have it run it as a real, honest to goodness different program then you'll need to use the Java [Process API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to actually spawn a proper new JVM. You can probably get away with this for a lot of things small programs:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        A.main(argsArray);
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply initializing a class will not invoke its `main()` method. You'd have to explicitly call it. The instantiation you have,

```
ClassA newobject = new ClassA();
```

will just call the constructor of `ClassA`, and that's it!

The only main() method that will be invoked by default is whatever class you pass in the command line, ie `java ClassB`.

As far as calling ClassA's `main()` method, you could do so by the following:

```
ClassA.main();
```

This is because the `main()` method is owned by the class since it is `static`. That all said, this is bad practice and is not advised.